# Ubuntu Server lm-sensors sensors detect showing 100 every time no devices

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a VMWare ESXI with a Ubuntu Server and recently been having some suspected overheating problems and I would like to check the sensors.
I have run sensors-detect and output of sensors gives nothing useful.

The server has Intel i7 QuadCore 3.5ghz.
Do I need to install any drivers on the **Guest (Ubuntu)**
Will these drivers cause any problems?
Will I need to restart the **host**?

sensors output:

[image]

IN the VMWARE here are my sensors:

[Vmware VCenter Health Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHsoA.png)

Answer (score 3):

You will not get proper hardware readings inside the Virtual Machine.

As long as the vendor specific hardware VIBs are installed on the ESXi server you should be able to see the current temperature status directly under 'Hardware status'. You can also define an alert directly on the ESXi or in VCenter.

[image]

Comment: I dont get the hardware status tab, I go into Configuration tab and then Health Status, although all it sais is Socket 1500 and sais OK there is no information as your image states such as Thermal Trip. The machine is basically a gaming PC which has been built from scratch (We didnt build it) which is quite bad since we know not much about the machine. It is an ASUS. So how can I install these Vendor specifiv VIBs?

Comment: An ASUS All Series motherboard